# Screen resolution wrong after suspend

Tags: ati

OK ladies and gents I'm a Gentoo (portable) and Arch (desktop) refugee so I'm still getting the feel for Ubuntu so bear with me. I installed 14.04 on my desktop along with fglrx 99% of things work fine after a bit of re-leaning my last problem is that after suspend my screen resolution resets not amount of my tinkering has fixed it. what futzing do I need to do with the AMD drivers to keep my screen resolution?

Chris

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is your desktop problem, but you can use this solution to get rid of this issue, run below command in terminal:

```
xrandr
```

It's tell you what resolutions your monitor supports.

Then create a bash script (e.g "restore_resolution.sh") with this lines of codes:
(put your resolution after xrandr -s)

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    thaw|resume)
        xrandr -s PUT_YOUR_RESOLUTION_HERE
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

move the file to this path:

```
/etc/pm/sleep.d/
```

and make sure it can be execute:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/restore_resolution.sh
```

it should fix your problem, after resume this script will be run and fixs your resolution.

Comment: xrandr is for multi-head is it not?

Comment: i think it can handle multi-heads too, I'm not sure.